# wget or curl via HTTP can't download if I use variables

Tags: curl, wget

I am trying to download a few thousands of pictures from a web server. The guys were very kind and gave me all the links to the original pictures but each picture is in its own folder. So what I try to do is write a simple script to get the links from a txt file and then use the last [foldername] from the path that includes the picture and add it to the [picturename]. The reason: some picture names are identical.

So, here is the script I was trying to make:

```
for path in $(cat bit4u_photos_2.txt)
do

curl echo $(echo $(echo $path | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $4}')$(echo $path | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $5}')) -O $(echo $(echo $path))

done
```

I also tried with variable names, still no success. I tried moving -O from one place to another as found in some comments on Google findings and also tried with wget. Always fails. The error for this version with curl is:

```
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
'url: (6) Couldn't resolve host '86755629e8836.jpg
```

now, the txt file contains for testing just 1 line and below I will place the new filename I need to get and the path where to get from (as it is in the txt file).

```
newfilename=867556-29e8836.jpg
path=http://just.razzi.me/photos/867556/29e8836.jpg
```

If I try to get them both with an echo it's absolutely insane the result:

```
echo "newfilename=$testwget"
echo "path=$path"
echo "$testwget $path"

Output:
newfilename=867556-29e8836.jpg
path=http://just.razzi.me/photos/867556/29e8836.jpg
 http://just.razzi.me/photos/867556/29e8836.jpg
```

Please help.